# Python socketserver список подключений(connection list)

Tags: python, сокет, python-3.x

Допустим задача стоит написать чат-сервер. Сообщение приходят на сервер и должно быть передано всем остальным пользователям. Как в socketserver' е поддерживать список активных подключений?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно создать словарь, в котором ключ - это имя/логин/никнейм пользователя, а значение - это его сессия. Как именно это сделать зависит от технологии, которую вы используете.

К примеру, в Tornado я использовал это так:

```
class PlansqTornadoChat(SockJSConnection):
    users = dict()

    @tornado.gen.engine
    def on_message(self, msg):
        data = proto.json_decode(msg)

        if data['type'] == 'auth':
            if data.get('sid', None):
                try:
                    ... код ...
                    self.users[self.user_sid] = self
                    ... еще код ...
```

То есть в качестве значения был использован SID пользователя (Second ID), а в качестве значения - открытое соединение конкретного пользователя.

Прошу обратить внимание, что я использовал подключение в on_message вместо on_open, но там есть свои причины.

Comment: Да, действительно, теперь понял глупость своего вопроса)